# Replace characters in Swift String?

Tags: swift

I have a string that contains a comma. However, I would like to replace the comma by a point. This must be possible unfortunately I can not get it done. I'm not just getting back the .5. The comma is away only everything that stonged for it unfortunately too.

```
let cijfers = "38,5"
let start = cijfers.startIndex;
let end = cijfers.index(cijfers.startIndex, offsetBy: 3);
let result = cijfers.replacingCharacters(in: start..<end, with: ".")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use `cijfers.replacingOccurrences` not on the correct way, for your purpose.
Try this:

```
let str = "38,5"
let replaced = str.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
print(replaced)
```